# How can I report in Salesforce cases open vs closed in one day

Tags: group-by, salesforce, report

We are trying to build a report in Salesforce for the last 30 days that shows for each day, the amount of cases opened and the amount of cases closed(in total, not how many of the opened were closed). It's just a workload comparison for the support team, so how many cases in vs how many cases out.

Something like

Day 1 . 46 cases opened. 34 cases closed.
Day 2 . 50 cases opened. 52 cases closed.
[...]
Day 30. 36 cases opened. 26 cases closed.

We'd graph that with side by side bars.

We can't get our way around to bucket those two different group by's. As cased closed don't necessarily belog to cases opened that day.

We tried grouping by cases open or closed.

Comment: "Clicks not code" questions are better fit for dedicated https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ site. More admins around there, higher chance for fast & accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal report on Case won't work because you want to count a record twice (once on creation, once on closing... and pray you never reopen cases)

1. Does it really have to be on single report? You could make a dashboard with 2 report components, that'd be easy, group 1st by CreatedDate, 2nd by ClosedDate.
2. Or try to run a report on Case History (assuming you do have field history tracking enabled on key fields)

Here's sample "stacked bar" chart of a "Case History" report

(but I have very simple lifecycle, just New -> Closed... if you have more statuses it'll be tricky to filter them out and focus on just closing. Maybe you have a field you set when closing and it's history tracked?)

[image]

3. There's a feature called Case Milestones, check if it could help.